# Edge, Vertex, and Face tool do not show up anymore on the menu

Tags: edit-mode, edges

The edge,vertex, and face tool in edit mode disappeared! How can I fix this?

[image: Edit Screen without edge/face/vertex select]

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once

Answer (score 0):

Even if this as already got an answer, I'm going to breifly explain you why.
I assume you are working with a Lattice. In lattices you can actually select only vertices, so there is no Vertices/Edge/Faces button. if you need to select an edge, just select the extreme vertices, so do for a Face.